# How to iterate over pandas df with a def function variable function

Tags: python, pandas

i hope you can guide me here, cause i am a little lost and not really experienced in python programing.

My goal: i have to calculate the "adducts" for a given "Compound", both represents numbes, but for eah "Compound" there are 46 different "Adducts".

Each adduct is calculated as follow:

Adduct 1 = [Exact_mass*M/Charge + Adduct_mass]

where exact_mass = number, M and Charge = number (1, 2, 3, etc) according to each type of adduct, Adduct_mass = number (positive or negative) according to each adduct.

My data: 2 data frames. One with the Adducts names, M, Charge, Adduct_mass. 
The other one correspond to the Compound_name and Exact_mass of the Compounds i want to iterate over (i just put a small data set)

Adducts: df_al

```
import pandas as pd 
data = [["M+3H", 3, 1, 1.007276], ["M+3Na", 3, 1, 22.989], ["M+H", 1, 1, 1.007276], ["2M+H", 1, 2, 1.007276], ["M-3H", 3, 1, -1.007276]]
df_al = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Ion_name", "Charge", "M", "Adduct_mass"])
```

Compounds: df

```
import pandas as pd 
data1 = [[1, "C3H64O7", 596.465179], [2, "C30H42O7", 514.293038], [4, "C44H56O8", 712.397498], [4, "C24H32O6S", 448.191949], [5, "C20H28O3", 316.203834]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=["CdId", "Formula", "exact_mass"])
```

My code:

```
df_name = df_al["Ion_name"]
df_mass = df_al["adduct_mass"]
df_div = df_al["Div"]
df_M = df_al["M"]
```

then i defined for each ion a function using the index to set each value

```
def A0(x):
    return x*df_M[0]/df_div[0] + df_mass[0]

def A1(x):
    return x*df_M[1]/df_div[1] + df_mass[1]

def A2(x):
    return x*df_M[2]/df_div[2] + df_mass[2]

def A3(x):
    return x*df_M[3]/df_div[3] + df_mass[3]

def A4(x):
    return x*df_M[4]/df_div[4] + df_mass[4]

def A5(x): 
    return x*df_M[5]/df_div[5] + df_mass[5]

def A6(x):
    return x*df_M[6]/df_div[6] + df_mass[6]
```

and so on, till func A46

then i .map each function to to each of the Compounds and i store each value in a new column in the df (Here is my other problem: how to add the name of each ion on the top of each column matching the corresponding function?)

```
df[df_name.loc[0]] = df["exact_mass"].map(A0)
df[df_name.loc[1]] = df["exact_mass"].map(A1)
df[df_name.loc[2]] = df["exact_mass"].map(A2)
df[df_name.loc[3]] = df["exact_mass"].map(A3)
df[df_name.loc[4]] = df["exact_mass"].map(A4)
df[df_name.loc[5]] = df["exact_mass"].map(A5)
df[df_name.loc[6]] = df["exact_mass"].map(A6)
```

.
.
.
and so on till applying A46.

I thing it could be a simpler way to def the function and that it changes according each ion (maybe a forloop?) and also a simpler way to apply the function and get the corresponding name without .loc each one.

Thanks!

Comment: You have given an example of your input data, perhaps you could also provide us with an example of your expected output?

Comment: sure! here is the main idea of the out put

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is using `functools.partial` together with `map`.

Given the regularity of your function calls, I would try something like:

```
from funtools import partial

def func(x, n):
    return x*df_M[n]/df_div[n] + df_mass[n]

for i in range(max_i): #change max_i with the integer you need
    df[df_name.loc[i]] = map(partial(func, n=i), df["exact_mass"])
    #df[df_name.loc[i]] = df["exact_mass"].map(partial(func, n=i)) should work as well
```

more info here https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functools.html#functools.partial

Answer (score 0):

Here's a proposition define

```
def A(x,i):
    return x*df_M[i]/df_div[i] + df_mass[i]
```

Then doing A(x,5) is the same as A5(x). Then you loop through all your stuff:

```
for i in range(47):
    df[df_name.loc[i]] = df['exact_mass'].map(lambda x: A(x,i))
```

I think there is probably a more elegant way to do this, but this should work.