# How to iterate over dfs and append data with combine names

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, slice

i have this problem to solve, this is a continuation of a previus question [How to iterate over pandas df with a def function variable function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54145284/how-to-iterate-over-pandas-df-with-a-def-function-variable-function) and the given answer worked perfectly, but now i have to append all the data in a 2 columns dataframe (Adduct_name and mass).

This is from the previous question:

My goal: i have to calculate the "adducts" for a given "Compound", both represents numbes, but for eah "Compound" there are 46 different "Adducts".

Each adduct is calculated as follow:

Adduct 1 = [Exact_mass*M/Charge + Adduct_mass]

where exact_mass = number, M and Charge = number (1, 2, 3, etc) according to each type of adduct, Adduct_mass = number (positive or negative) according to each adduct.

My data: 2 data frames. One with the Adducts names, M, Charge, Adduct_mass. The other one correspond to the Compound_name and Exact_mass of the Compounds i want to iterate over (i just put a small data set)

Adducts: df_al

```
import pandas as pd 
data = [["M+3H", 3, 1, 1.007276], ["M+3Na", 3, 1, 22.989], ["M+H", 1, 1, 
1.007276], ["2M+H", 1, 2, 1.007276], ["M-3H", 3, 1, -1.007276]]
df_al = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Ion_name", "Charge", "M", "Adduct_mass"])
```

Compounds: df

```
import pandas as pd 
data1 = [[1, "C3H64O7", 596.465179], [2, "C30H42O7", 514.293038], [4, 
"C44H56O8", 712.397498], [4, "C24H32O6S", 448.191949], [5, "C20H28O3", 
316.203834]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=["CdId", "Formula", "exact_mass"])
```

The solution to this problem was:

```
df_name = df_al["Ion_name"]
df_mass = df_al["Adduct_mass"]
df_div = df_al["Charge"]
df_M = df_al["M"]
#Defining general function 
def Adduct(x,i):
    return x*df_M[i]/df_div[i] + df_mass[i]

#Applying general function in a range from 0 to 5. 
for i in range(5):
    df[df_name.loc[i]] = df['exact_mass'].map(lambda x: Adduct(x,i))
```

Output

```
    Name exact_mass  M+3H       M+3Na        M+H        2M+H        M-3H
0   a   596.465179  199.829002  221.810726  597.472455  1193.937634 197.814450
1   b   514.293038  172.438289  194.420013  515.300314  1029.593352 170.423737
2   c   712.397498  238.473109  260.454833  713.404774  1425.802272 236.458557
3   d   448.191949  150.404592  172.386316  449.199225  897.391174  148.390040
4   e   316.203834  106.408554  128.390278  317.211110  633.414944  104.39400
```

Now that is the rigth calculations but i need now a file where: 
-only exists 2 columns (Name and mass)
-All the different adducts are appended one after another

desired out put

```
 Name     Mass 
 a_M+3H  199.82902
 a_M+3Na 221.810726
 a_M+H   597.472455
 a_2M+H  1193.937634
 a_M-3H  197.814450 
 b_M+3H  514.293038
 .
 . 
 .
 c_M+3H
```

and so on.

Also i need to combine the name of the respective compound with the ion form (M+3H, M+H, etc).

At this point i have no code for that.

I would apprecitate any advice and a better approach since the begining.

---

This part is an update of the question above:

Is posible to obtain and ouput like this one:

```
  Name     Mass       RT
 a_M+3H  199.82902     1
 a_M+3Na 221.810726    1
 a_M+H   597.472455    1
 a_2M+H  1193.937634   1
 a_M-3H  197.814450    1
 b_M+3H  514.293038    3
 .           
 . 
 .
 c_M+3H                2
```

The RT is the same value for all forms of a compound, in this example is RT for a =1, b = 3, c =2, etc.

Is posible to incorporate (Keep this column) from the data set df (which i update here below)?. As you can see that df has more columns like "Formula" and "RT" which desapear after calculations.

```
import pandas as pd 
data1 = [[a, "C3H64O7", 596.465179, 1], [b, "C30H42O7", 514.293038, 3], [c, 
"C44H56O8", 712.397498, 2], [d, "C24H32O6S", 448.191949, 4], [e, "C20H28O3", 
316.203834, 1.5]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=["Name", "Formula", "exact_mass", "RT"])
```

---

Part three! (sorry and thank you)

this is a trial i did on a small data set (df) using the code below, with the same df_al of above.

df= 
[image]

Code

```
#Defining variables for calculation

df_name = df_al["Ion_name"]
df_mass = df_al["Adduct_mass"]
df_div = df_al["Charge"]
df_M = df_al["M"]
df_ID= df["Name"]

#Defining the RT dictionary

RT = dict(zip(df["Name"], df["RT"]))

#Removing RT column

df=df.drop(columns=["RT"])

#Defining general function 

def Adduct(x,i):
    return x*df_M[i]/df_div[i] + df_mass[i]

#Applying general function in a range from 0 to 46. 

for i in range(47):
    df[df_name.loc[i]] = df['exact_mass'].map(lambda x: Adduct(x,i)) 

df
```

output

[image]

```
#Melting

df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Name'], var_name = "Adduct", value_name= "Exact_mass", value_vars=[x for x in df.columns if 'Name' not in x and 'exact' not in x])

df['name'] = df.apply(lambda x:x[0] + "_" + x[1], axis=1)

df['RT'] = df.Name.apply(lambda x: RT[x[0]] if x[0] in RT else np.nan)

del df['Name']

del df['Adduct']

df['RT'] = df.name.apply(lambda x: RT[x[0]] if x[0] in RT else np.nan)

df
```

output

[image]

Why NaN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I will go about it, pandas.melt comes to rescue:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from io import StringIO

s = StringIO('''
    Name exact_mass  M+3H       M+3Na        M+H        2M+H        M-3H
0   a   596.465179  199.829002  221.810726  597.472455  1193.937634 197.814450
1   b   514.293038  172.438289  194.420013  515.300314  1029.593352 170.423737
2   c   712.397498  238.473109  260.454833  713.404774  1425.802272 236.458557
3   d   448.191949  150.404592  172.386316  449.199225  897.391174  148.390040
4   e   316.203834  106.408554  128.390278  317.211110  633.414944  104.39400
''')

df = pd.read_csv(s, sep="\s+")

df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Name'], value_vars=[x for x in df.columns if 'Name' not in x and 'exact' not in x])



df['name'] = df.apply(lambda x:x[0] + "_" + x[1], axis=1)

del df['Name']
del df['variable']


RT = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':5, 'e':1.5}

df['RT'] = df.name.apply(lambda x: RT[x[0]] if x[0] in RT else np.nan)
df
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Comment: question! this is just a few data of the real df, in this case for the value_vars are just five of 46 (whole data), should i  type one by one?

Comment: Nope, let me modify to take all columns. Two mins

Comment: dear @PankajJoshi, if in the df previous to melting exist a column that i want to keep, for example molecular formula (srt), how can i make that?

Comment: Could you please add this to your question with example, it will be a bit more clear.

Comment: @PanjakJoshi i just finished updating the question! kind regards

Comment: @LuisManuelQuirosguerrero sorry for the late response. I have modified the code. You will have to create  a dictionary `RT` which will have the mapping.

Comment: @PanjakJoshi i just upgrade the code and i do not know why i`m obtaining NaN in the RT column.

Comment: @LuisManuelQuirosguerrero is the key is missing in the `RT` dictionary you will get an NaN

Comment: @PanjakJosh, thanks, but still does not work, i am implementing this code over a huge datafram, and it works perfectly just until i put the code for introducing the RT. I created the RT dictionary from the original data frame `RT = dict(zip(df["Name"], df["RT]))` and then is i ask for the dictionay content, is basically the same type of output as yours here above {'BTX': 6.1, '251A': 12.8, '275A': 11.7}.  I don`t know why after runing it still getting NaN.

Comment: are all entries NaN?

Comment: Yes, all entries are NaN!

Comment: @PanjakJoshi i just upload the question!  Whe i run your code as write here with this very same example works perfectly,  even though it works perfectly for all my others trials on different DataFrames but not the part of adding the RT

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187225/discussion-between-pankaj-joshi-and-luis-manuel-quiros-guerrero).